# Identifying cells overlapping in multiple rasters using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, multi-band, cell-size

I have a range of forest raster TIFF files over a 10 year period, and want to create a fresh raster of locations where it has been forest for 3 or more years.

I know I can merge them into a multi-band raster, but then how could I observe the areas of overlapping cells?

[image]

Each year's file is quite large, consisting of 468 MB. My PC has 32 GB RAM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to SUM the cells of your raster data, then you can use [Cell Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiscellstatistics), and use `Sum` under Statistic. From the help:

> The Cell statistics algorithm computes a value for each cell of the
> output raster. At each cell location, the output value is defined as a
> function of all overlaid cell values of the input rasters.

[image]

You can find it in the `Processing toolbox → Raster Analysis → Cell Statistics`

If you want to multiply the raster data, you can use Raster Calculator:

```
Raster (Menu toolbar) → Raster Calculator
```

[image]